# endless video playback ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I wanted to play a video as background of my view so I decided to use MPMoviePlayerController to play endless video and I made something like that:

```
NSString *pathForFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clear" ofType:@"mp4"];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
player.fullscreen = YES;
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
player.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathForFile];
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[player.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[player.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[player.view setAlpha:0.0f];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:player.view];
[player prepareToPlay];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:player];

- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {
if (note.object == player) {
    NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey"] integerValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        [player play];
    }
}
```

My method called every time the video ends, but player don't playing video again. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; use this line in  if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) { } condition

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (note.object == player) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey"] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
             player.seekToTime[kCMTimeZero];
             // you must have to give time to start video again so use seekToTime
             [player play];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexChekel another option for your solution is AVPlayerLooper

Comment: different times, I think it's MPMoviePlayerController bug @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: @AlexChekel possibility that MPMoviePlayerController had some bug but i suggest you use avplayer for looping